# error in relation between two models - ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

please I need help ! seems like my association doesn't work correctly but i cant find what's wrong.
i have a relation between student and guardian , student has many guardians and guardians belongs to student

i can't get the admission number which inserted in student form , to the guardians form , seems like no relation but i cant solve it !

I Dont knw why users down vote my question ! :D i just cant make this work so i asked for a help :O

students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @student = Student.all
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
      flash[:success] = ' Student Record Saved Successfully. Please fill the Parent Details.'
      redirect_to new_guardian_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end
end
```

guardians_controller.rb

```
class GuardiansController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @guardian = Guardian.new
  end

  def edit
  end
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address_line1, :address_line2, :admission_date, :admission_no, :birth_place, :blood_group, :city,
                  :class_roll_no, :date_of_birth, :email, :first_name, :gender, :language, :last_name, :middle_name,
                  :phone1, :phone2, :post_code, :religion, :country_id, :nationality_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :batch
  belongs_to :nationality , class_name: 'Country'
  has_many :guardians
  has_many :student_previous_subject_marks
  has_one :student_previous_data
end
```

guardian.rb

```
class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :dob, :education, :email, :first_name, :income, :last_name, :mobile_phone, :occupation,
                  :office_address_line1, :office_address_line2, :office_phone1, :office_phone2, :relation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :student
end
```

guardians/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Admission</h1>
<h4>Step 2 - Parent details</h4>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 offset1 hero-unit">
    <%= form_for @guardian do |f| %>
        <% if @guardian.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@guardian.errors.count, 'error') %>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <% @guardian.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li>* <%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <fieldset>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label 'Student Admission number' %>
          <%= f.text_field @guardian.student.admission_no %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first thing is that, as your guardian model suggests, you do not have any field to store student's reference i guess. So, please add that first like add a field student_id in guardians model. Also you do not have admission_no field either in guardians model. So, if you want to store admission_no then add a field for this also in DB, if you just want to display the value, in guardian model add

```
attr_accessor :admission_no
```

Now, since in your new action of GuardiansController, you are creating an object which is not yet associated with any record in students table. So using nested resource like bachan said in his answer you can achieve the goal.

Create the nested resource :-

```
resources :students do
 resources :guardians
end
```

and then in new action of GuardiansController

```
def new
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  @guardian = Guardian.new
end
```

Now replace your form_for with

```
<%= form_for([@student, @guardian]) do |f| %>
  .............
  <%= f.text_field :admission_no, :value => @student.admission_no %>
  .............
<% end%>
```

if you want to store id of the student also in guardians table. If not then you can use

```
<%= form_for(@guardian, :url => student_guardians_path(@student), :method => :post) do |f| %>
  .............
  <%= f.text_field :admission_no, :value => @student.admission_no %>
  .............
<% end%>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: NoMethodError in Guardians#new 
undefined method `merge' for "301":String

Extracted source (around line #63):

60:         <div class="field">
61: 
62:           <%= f.label 'Student Admission number' %>
63:           <%= f.text_field :admission_no, @student.admission_no %>
64: 
65:         </div>

Comment: hey i got this work i found the missing shoud be like this >>>

<%= f.text_field :admission_no, value: @student.admission_no %>

Answer (score 1):

In the new action of guardians_controller, you have created the blank object of the guardian. So you don't get the value of the student admission number. In this case, you need to add nested resources.

in your routes file add the following code

```
resources :students do
 resources :guardians
end
```

Now change the code of the create action of the students_controller

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
      flash[:success] = ' Student Record Saved Successfully. Please fill the Parent Details.'
      redirect_to new_student_guardian_path(@student)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

And you need to add the following code to the new action of guardians_controller as well.

```
def new
    @guardian = Guardian.new({:student_id => params[:student_id]})
end
```

Now you can get the value of related student's admission number in your html form.

In the guardians/new.html.erb, you need to modify

```
<%= form_for(@guardian, :url => student_guardians_path(params[:student_id]), :method => 'post') do |f| %>
```

Comment: undefined method 'guardians_path' for#<#<Class:0xaf28988>

in this line <%= form_for @guardian do |f| %>

Comment: @vikram can you type your answer to try it ?

Comment: In the guardians/new.html.erb, you need to modify
<%= form_for(@guardian, :url => student_guardians_path(params[:student_id]), :method => 'post' )do |f| %>